# Laika vs Velocity on meteor TDD

Tags: meteor

Hello I am new in TDD on Meteor.

I found 2 tdd frameworks laika and velocity.

what is difference between both?

when I use laika and velocity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably not an appropriate question for SO, but I struggled with this myself so I'll share my experiences and thoughts.

First, Velocity is not a testing framework in itself. It's really a framework for testing frameworks. It provides unified reporting and execution management. You don't just use Velocity; you use the testing frameworks it supports, currently: sanjo:jasmine, mike:mocha, and clinical:nightwatch.

Arunoda (the author of Laika) has moved on to other work (a victim of his success with Kadira) so I don't think Laika is going to be moving forward. It's not a target for being added to the velocity framework (by Arunoda at least). I think that's a shame because it's the only testing framework that I could get to work out of the box and it's what I use now for the limited integration and client-side testing that I do. I strongly believe that its use of phantomjs is a much better than sanjo:jasmine (chrome) or clinical:nightwatch (firefox) attempting to use real browsers. I still recommend Laika for now but I suspect it will break at some point and won't be fixed rapidly.

TinyTest is being added to Velocity. As far as I can tell, it's server-side oriented AND it's a hurdle for new users because it requires learning about and using packages which are generally a more advanced Meteor topic. I got it running by following the instructions but I never used it. This is mostly due to the fact that I tend to write as much code as possible as non-Meteor-specific and do all that unit testing with node-unit. Webstorm has great node-unit support and I've written thousands of tests using it.

I have yet to get clinical:nightwatch to run... under Velocity or otherwise. I've tried twice and both attempts were just before 1.0 release so it may be better now, but the documentation is not in good shape and the team has been focused elsewhere with the 1.0 release. I think the BDD "describe" syntax is too verbose so mike:mocha doesn't interest me. I realize that Laika uses mocha under the covers also but it doesn't require the BDD-style "describe" syntax and the Laika examples make perfect sense to me. After struggling with nightwatch's real browser approach, I am totally convinced that headless phantomjs is the way to go so I didn't even try sanjo:jasmine.

Despite the current bad state of Velocity, I think it is the way to go moving forward. It will get better and if my experience with Meteor development in general is duplicated with respect to Velocity, it will get better fast. As a new Meteor developer, I suggest that you try Velocity. Failing that, if your interest is mostly server-side unit testing, then fall back to TinyTest. Only if that gets real frustrating would I suggest you pick up Laika and then expect it to break some day. Hopefully, that's far enough down the road for the Velocity situation to have greatly improved.

Comment: Thanks for this thoughtful answer. I am new to Meteor and stuck for choices. I'm running on Windows and Velocity doesn't work at all at the moment so my choice is either TinyTest (very limited) or Laika (going to break soon if not already broken). *sigh*

Comment: @Alveoli, Let me know what direction you go. I am now motivated to do some Windows development. I would try Laika if I were you. I hear that phantomjs runs under node.js for Windows so I suspect Laika has the best chance of working. Maybe a few of us can maintain it.