# Cloud-based Meteor with Velocity

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

Being that Meteor on Windows does not currently support Velocity/Jasmine, I would like to use a cloud-based solution for running Meteor with Velocity.  But so far I have not had success.  I have tried Nitrous, Codeanywhere, Koding, and Cloud9.

Comment: I think one of the main problems is that Velocity relies on Meteor running in debug mode (what you get with `meteor` or `meteor run` locally), and turns off for production deployments (running the Node app that you get from `meteor build`). Most of the cloud-based solutions, as well as Meteor Up, use `meteor build` in the deployment pipeline. I'm still working on a solution to this myself...

Answer (score 0):

I also use the Meteor Windows Preview and the same issue.  See my SO: [Easiest way to create mobile apps on official Meteor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197230/easiest-way-to-create-mobile-apps-on-official-meteor-for-windows)

I had the additional constraint that I want to compile Mobile Apps which is currently not supported by the Windows Preview.

I've not had success with cloud-based solutions either beyond very basic test apps.  The whole chain is just too fragile, there's often something you need to configure that you can't get at in a cloud solution.  Basically, your options are:

1. Vagrant
2. Dual-boot (thanks @sbking)
3. Buy a Mac

I would recommend 3 because it will save you time (and therefore money).  The first 2 are fiddly, just adding more sys admin work when we should all be coding :)

**ALTERNATIVELY**

Switch testing tools to Laika.  See related SO: [Laika vs Velocity on meteor TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989392/laika-vs-velocity-on-meteor-tdd)

Laika (apparently) still works for the moment, even though it is no longer officially supported.  I will be using it for my current project in the next few weeks.

I'd be really interested to hear what solution you go for.

Comment: I am thinking of using Spacejam https://www.npmjs.com/package/spacejam, http://practicalmeteor.com/testing-meteor-packages-command-line-travis-ci/ Have you tried that perhaps?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the cloud-based fragility which you mentioned?  From what you write, even if testing were not an issue, there are still other problems.  Please tell me all about them, as I was planning to rely on cloud-based development.  Thanks!

Comment: I just came across gagarin (https://github.com/anticoders/gagarin), which is billed as Laika 2.0 Any thoughts?

Comment: Update: I have had good results with Spacejam on Nitrous (both client and server testing); however, Codeanywhere had problems with Spacejam.

Comment: Hi, I've not come across Spacejam - good to hear it's working. As regards fragility, I'm thinking dependencies that you don't expect to have that might creep up on you... off the top of my head, say CollectionFS's image functions needing imagemagick installed on the box. (I just looked at Nitrous and you should be ok for that particular one http://help.nitrous.io/box-interpreters-and-tools/)

Comment: Regarding dependencies in cloud development, even if say imagemagick were not available from Nitrous, I could easily install it myself (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php), just like I would on my own machine.  So I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of offering you a pocket-knife when you want a power-tool, there is a meteor package, jasmine-green, that does **not** require Velocity and therefore works well with Cloud9. While this means that you would not have the full capabilities of a velocity-based jasmine or mocha package, it is a lot better than nothing. Just type:

meteor add fongandrew:jasmine-green

It might be a stopgap while you find a better long-run solution.